# Interference with ideal beam

Tags: optics, energy-conservation, interference

I'm thinking about this setup and am a little confused:

[image]

An ideal beam (thin, no divergence) is entering from the left. It is split up by an ideal (50:50) beam splitter BS. They are united again at the screen S by an appropriately placed mirror M. The screen shall be completely absorbing.

I think it should be possible adjust the dotted path in such a way that there is destructive interference with the dashed path at S. But where did all the energy go? Which of the above points is impossible to achieve?

Comment: you can't have a non-diverging beam.

Answer (score 1):

> An ideal beam (thin, no divergence)

from which one can say that inclined (to each other and to the screen) plane wavefronts of a finite width are incident on the screen.
At one point there is no net electric (and magnetic) field but what is happening around that point?
There is a net electric (and magnetic) field with energy carried by the fields being absorbed by the screen.

Answer (score 1):

As the two beam interfering are not colinear, you will get vertical interference fringes. You can adjust the distance to have destructive interference for the central fringe. The energy will go on the constructive interference of the other fringes.

So for me the unachievable in this experiment is to select only one fringe without using a vertical slit.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the beams interfere destructively at the screen does not mean that they will destroy each other everywhere else.

After the beams interfere in the plane of the screen, they will be partially reflected and partially absorbed by the screen, i.e., their energy would not disappear.

In this sense, it is no different than the interference between any two properly polarized coherent independent beams, which could take place anywhere the beams overlap, but would not affect the beams once they have passed the overlapping area.

Comment: But at the single spot on the screen where the individual beams hit there is destructive interference, for me that means that no brightness/intensity /energy gets there. So nothing can be reflected /absorbed.

Comment: @Jasper That's not how it works. According to the principle of superposition, each beam (wave) will behave exactly the same before and after the area of interference as it would if the other beam (wave) was not present at all.

Comment: Yes, thats fine for intersecting beams. I'm fine with "beams after point of no intensity". But the screen prohibits propagation (and also let's consider a perfectly absorbing screen)

Comment: @Jasper If the screen was completely absorbing the beams, their energy would be turned into heat, i.e., the screen would become worm - as much as it would if the two beams were interfering constructively or in any other way.

Comment: I have trouble seeing this. Destructive interference = electric fields are opposing each other at the screen, so there is no net field, so no changing field, so no transferred energy, no brightness, no heat.

Comment: @Jasper "so there is no net field" at that point. It does not say that it also true beyond that point.

Comment: There is also no real practical way to make a non-diverging beam. You might get perfect destructive interference at the center of your beams,  but constructive interference elsewhere in the transverse directions.

Comment: @Jasper And just before and just after, as is self-evident if you look at any interference picture. The only way two beams can destroy each other everywhere is that they originate from the same point and are out of phase, which means that there would not be any beams to start with.

Comment: Interference in waves does not destroy the energy, it is only a transient situation where you see no amplitude but the energy is stored in the field (or water). Another example is the double slit experiment, if 100 photons go thru the slits and make a pattern it has the same intensity as if 100 photons just impacted the screen.

Answer (score 0):

There are some neat things to consider in your experiment, but first of all, no energy is lost. A similar example is 2 tsunami's, one leaving Japan and the other leaving LA, and one being a depression/subduction and the other being the opposite.  The waves meet at Hawaii, they cancel, everyone is saved, but unfortunately after Hawaii the waves reemerge, one continuing on its way to Japan and the other to LA. This is conservation of energy.

With your experiment consider another example of a thin film reflection coating, say the coat is 500nm thick which will block all 1um (IR) light (provided it is coming straight on).  What happens to this light?, it gets reflected becoming a standing wave with the source.  I have assumed your ideal source is monochromatic.  I think your setup will effectively be similar, the energy building up in the source.

(Another detail to consider in your beamsplitter is that one of the waves reflecting of the front face or the one emerging actually gets a phase change in the process.)

Comment: Yes there will be some phase change due to the splitter, but the mirror can be positioned accordingly to produce destructive interference. There will be no reflection to the source in this setup.

Comment: Sorry, I thought S was another mirror.  Ok so a screen is rough so that means mostly that no 2 photons will hit the same spot and due to the deeper scattering the photons will NOT interact, simply just scatter back out.

Comment: However if your light source had some coherence to it, it would be a whole new story.  In fact you would not need a BS and M at all to cause interference, in this case it is called speckle.  Moreover any light source, even sunlight, has some level of coherence but its typically difficult to observe without special equipment ( like an interferometer ).